# How can I sort a Hash of hashes of Array of Arrays by (inner) array in value in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, multidimensional-array, data-structures, hash

I have this data-structure, product of my data:

```
'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4' => {
    '-1.19 +' => [
        [
            '+', '2', '120', '0.76', '0.809799'
        ]
    ],
    '-1.19 -' => [
        [
            '-', '2', '120', '0.19', '0.585090'
        ]
    ]
}
```

I want to organize it according to the **last value** of the 'inside' array that corresponds to the data grouped by a 'inside' key, in this case: '-1.19 +' and '-1.19 -'. Because I want to put the the key that has the greatest value of the inside array, on the bottom of my hash.

In other words:

```
'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4' => {
    '-1.19 -' => [
        [
            '-', '2', '120', '0.19', '0.585090'
        ]
    ],
    '-1.19 +' => [
        [
            '+', '2', '120', '0.76', '0.809799'
        ]
    ]
}
```

How Can I do this task, because I want to select the key that has the greater value, so I want to shift the other ones.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're doing something wrong when you use things like `locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4` as hash keys. It looks like you're using an entire line from a space- or tab-separated file as a key; instead, consider splitting out the relevant pieces of data and using human-readable names as keys, e.g. `my %loci = ( locus4 => { width => 45880, type => 'GABA3' } );` (I have no idea what your data really represents so I just made these up, but I hope you get the gist).

Comment: The main idea, is organise. So, I want to create this key for the %hash to classify my tabulated-data...Any suggestions to organise or to reference in two different strings those values? Because I can compare with a conditional.

Comment: In order to organize your data we'll need to become for familiar with your data domain. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

To get the last element, use the index of -1.

```
my $inner_hash = $hash{'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4'};

my @sorted = sort { $inner_hash->{$a}[-1]
                    <=>
                    $inner_hash->{$b}[-1]
                } keys %$inner_hash;
print "@sorted\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort a list by comparing some expression on each element individually, you might like to use the collection of functions in `List::UtilsBy` called `sort_by`. Specifically in this case as the key expression is returning a number to be compared numerically, you'll want to use `nsort_by`:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by';

my @sorted = nsort_by { $_->[-1] } @items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in the hash doesn't have any order so if you want to have keys in order you have to change your inner hash into an array.

```
my %hash = (
    'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4'
        => {
        '-1.19 +' => [ [ '+', '2', '120', '0.76', '0.809799' ] ],
        '-1.19 -' => [ [ '-', '2', '120', '0.19', '0.585090' ] ]
        }
);

for my $value ( values %hash ) {
    $value = [
        map +[ $_, $value->{$_} ],
        sort { $value->{$a}[0][-1] <=> $value->{$b}[0][-1] } keys %$value
    ];
}
```

The result will be

```
'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4'
    => [
    [ '-1.19 -', [ [ '-', '2', '120', '0.19', '0.585090' ] ] ],
    [ '-1.19 +', [ [ '+', '2', '120', '0.76', '0.809799' ] ] ]
    ]
```

I would recommend removing double array in inside so code would look like:

```
for my $value ( values %hash ) {
    $value = [
        map +[ $_, $value->{$_}[0] ],
        sort { $value->{$a}[0][-1] <=> $value->{$b}[0][-1] } keys %$value
    ];
}
```

and the result:

```
'locus4 >9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570 45880 46000 locus4'
    => [
    [ '-1.19 -', [ '-', '2', '120', '0.19', '0.585090' ] ],
    [ '-1.19 +', [ '+', '2', '120', '0.76', '0.809799' ] ]
    ]
```